# Login servlet & jsp with boolean admin in User class

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

The login doesn't work when i get access with all privileges and if i do login with a normal user it redirect me to /admin instead of /app, i tried to solve the problem but i don't know what am i doing wrong. 
I want to create an unique admin where the username: admin and password: admin,
I have an User class with boolean attribute called admin.
Here the code:

WebFilter for Users:

```
@WebFilter("/app/*")
public class FiltroRegistro implements Filter {


    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        HttpSession session = req.getSession(false);
        String loginURI = req.getContextPath() + "/login.jsp";


        if (session != null && session.getAttribute("usuario") != null) {

            chain.doFilter(req, res);

        } else {
            res.sendRedirect(loginURI);
        }

    }
```

WebFilter for admin:

```
@WebFilter("/admin/*") public class FiltroAdministrador implements
   Filter {
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        HttpSession session = req.getSession(false);
        String loginURI = req.getContextPath() + "/login.jsp";

        if (session != null && session.getAttribute("administrador") != null) {

                chain.doFilter(req, res);

        } else {
            res.sendRedirect(loginURI);
        }

    }
```

Login servlet:

```
@WebServlet("/FiltroServlet")
public class FiltroRegistroServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

    String nombreUsuario = request.getParameter("nombreUsuario");
    String contrasenia = request.getParameter("contrasenia");

    GestionUsuarios gestionUsuarios = new GestionUsuarios();

    Usuario admin = gestionUsuarios.registrarAdministrador(nombreUsuario, contrasenia);
    //Usuario admin = gestionUsuarios.registrarAdministrador(nombreUsuario, contrasenia);
    Usuario usuario = gestionUsuarios.registrarUsuario(nombreUsuario, contrasenia);

    if (admin != null) {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
        session.setAttribute("administrador", admin);

        response.sendRedirect("admin/TablaEventosAdmin");


    } else if (usuario != null) {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
        session.setAttribute("usuario", usuario);
        response.sendRedirect("app/TablaEventosServlet");
        response.sendRedirect("loginError.jsp");
    } else {
        response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
    }

}
```

Login method in business layer for Users and Admin, and admin create by default (all in the same class)

```
public GestionUsuarios() {
        daoUsuario = new DaoUsuarioHibernate();

        Usuario admin = new Usuario("admin", "admin", true);

        daoUsuario.add(admin);
    } 
public Usuario registrarUsuario(String nombreUsuario, String contrasenia) {
        return daoUsuario.ObtenerUsuarioPorNombreYContrasenia(new Usuario(nombreUsuario, contrasenia, false));

    }

public Usuario registrarAdministrador(String usuario, String contrasenia){

        return daoUsuario.ObtenerUsuarioPorNombreYContrasenia(new Usuario(usuario,contrasenia, true));
    }
```

[The jsp structure, /app for normal users and /admin for all privileges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVlYb.png)

Comment: try to specify 
@WebFilter(filterName="FiltroAdministrador", urlPatterns={ "/admin/*" })

Comment: very thank you, i can acess now but both users (admin and normal users) go to /admin jsp :S

Comment: probably your `admin != 0` is always true?

Comment: yes it is, should i create admin only one time with true value an then comment the objet?